# Tensorflow loss minimization is increasing loss

Tags: tensorflow, training-data, gradient-descent, tensorboard

I implemented the linear regression model shown on Tensorflow's main page: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Model parameters
W = tf.Variable([.3], tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], tf.float32)
# Model input and output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = W * x + b
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
# loss
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y)) # sum of the squares
# optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
# training data
x_train = [1,2,3,4]
y_train = [0,-1,-2,-3]
# training loop
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init) # reset values to wrong
for i in range(1000):
  sess.run(train, {x:x_train, y:y_train})

# evaluate training accuracy
curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss  = sess.run([W, b, loss], {x:x_train, y:y_train})
print("W: %s b: %s loss: %s"%(curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss))
```

However, when I change the training data to x_train=[2,4,6,8] and y_train=[3,4,5,6],
the loss starts to increase over time until it reaches 'nan'

Comment: How are your weights and biases changing overtime? As another note you should use reduce_mean instead of reduce_sum.

Comment: My weights and biases are taking on increasingly large values, and they are alternating between large positive and negative values. Are you asking me to use reduce_mean because then the computed gradient is lower than what you get using reduce_sum? But I don't see how that would help.

Comment: Hmm the only other thing I can think of is to decrease the learning rate.  Honestly everything else seems fine.  If your learning rate is too large it can lead to you continuously doing worse with respect to your loss as the gradients will continue to increase with each step.  Try making it smaller and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6416660/steven), you should probably use reduce_mean(), which seems to fix the problem of the increasing loss function. Note that I also increased the number of training steps since reduce_mean() appears to need a bit longer to converge. Be careful with increasing the learning rate, since this may reproduce the problem. Instead, if training time is not a critical factor, you might want to decrease the learning rate and increase the number of training iterations further.

With the reduce_sum() function it worked well for me after decreasing the learning rate from 0.01 to 0.001. Again, thanks to [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6416660/steven) for the suggestion.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Model parameters
W = tf.Variable([.3], tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], tf.float32)
# Model input and output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = W * x + b
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
# loss
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(linear_model - y)) # sum of the squares
# optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
# training data
x_train = [2,4,6,8]
y_train = [0,3,4,5]
# training loop
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init) # reset values to wrong
for i in range(5000):
    sess.run(train, {x:x_train, y:y_train})

    # evaluate training accuracy
    curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss  = sess.run([W, b, loss], {x:x_train, y:y_train})
    print("W: %s b: %s loss: %s"%(curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss))
```